# VirtualBox Ubuntu VM doesn't automatically sync time with host even with Guest Additions installed

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, sync, ubuntu-12.04, guest-additions

I'm running a Ubuntu VM with VirtualBox and I have both the `dkms` and `virtualbox-guest-additions` packages installed. I read in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/335873/149613) that the system clock should sync with the host automatically with the Guest Additions, but mine doesn't seem to be doing that. What are some possible reasons / how do I rectify this? I've tried searching for this all over but most of the hits I get off Google tell you how to *disable* the automatic time sync, not enable it.

My host machine is running OS X 10.8, if that's of any help.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what version of Virtualbox are you using?  One would think the tutorial on how to disable could be used to enabled it by changing a single step.  Can you link to one such guide?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and VirtualBox 4.2.18. I initially followed [this](https://sites.google.com/site/iancharestphd/aide-memoire/installingubuntu1204ltswithguestadditionsinvirtualbox) small post to install Guest Additions. I know what you mean, my suspicion is also that the answer is very simple, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out I needed to install the `ntp` package, in addition to the two others I mentioned above.

The date/time after I woke my computer up from sleep:

```
$ date
Wed Sep 25 12:50:25 EDT 2013
```

Then, to correct it:

```
$ sudo service ntp stop
 * Stopping NTP server ntpd                          
$ sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org
25 Sep 13:22:45 ntpdate[15379]: step time server 109.169.89.48 offset 1880.691920 sec
$ sudo service ntp start
[sudo] password for yiqing: 
 * Starting NTP server ntpd
```

Now synced to the real date/time:

```
$ date
Wed Sep 25 13:23:07 EDT 2013
```

Once I rebooted, I found that my VM's system clock synced to my host as desired.

Comment: _"I found that my VM's system clock synced to my host as desired"_

Not to your host but to an external NTP server - there is a big difference, this approach requires network connectivity for the guest system whereas VirtualBox tools can accomplish actual time sync from host system without network connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming virtualbox-guest-additions is installed, if time-sync with the host is not working, you can enable it with:

#### Commands to be run from the Host

```
# Synchronize the time with the host every 60 seconds (Default 10 seconds)
VBoxManage guestproperty set "${VB_VM_NAME}" "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-interval" 60000
# Adjust in drift increments of 1 second (Default 100 milliseconds)
VBoxManage guestproperty set "${VB_VM_NAME}" "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-min-adjust" 1000
# Adjust if out of sync by more than 30 seconds (Default 20 minutes!)
VBoxManage guestproperty set "${VB_VM_NAME}" "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold" 30000
```

Info comes from https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=90233

This is a much better solution than using NTP, because whenever the VM or the Host resume from suspend/pause/hibernate, the time-sync would happen right away.

I'd live very much to know why wouldn't it (time-sync with host) be working if the guest-additions are installed and running (happened to me as well). Please comment if you have a clue/pointer.