# How do I sync the time on my Linux Mint VM with my Windows 7 host?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

I'm running Linux Mint 17 VM using VirtualBox on a Windows 7 (host). I've followed the steps found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/649661/virtualbox-ubuntu-vm-doesnt-automatically-sync-time-with-host-even-with-guest-a) and installed all three packages, but I still can't make the time sync with the host.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to sync time between VM and Host, just sync both with a NTP Server (for instance, pool.ntp.org). The result will be identical: Both having the same date and time.

**In your Linux Mint VM**

1. Open terminal with “Ctrl+Alt+T” and type command `sudo apt-get install ntp`, after a `sudo apt-get update`
2. Verify NTP service is running by using command `sudo service ntp status`.

**In your Windows 7 Host**

3. Right-click on the Windows clock and choose “Adjust Date/Time”
4. Select the "Internet Time" tab and click the "Change Settings" button on the bottom of the screen
5. Activate the checkbox "Synchronize with an Internet Time Server" and input "pool.ntp.org"
6. Click on "Update Now"

Finally, check that the time is the same on both VM and host.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick reply but I haven't been able to resolve the issue with this method. A few things worth mentioning though: A) Windows (host) tells the right time though the I can't update the time settings (I get the message, "An error occured while Windows was synchronizing with pool.ntp.org"). I tried to fix this (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-wont-synchronize-with-timewindowscom/d81a02ad-2334-488d-8829-d7ae03c1f55a?db=5) but was unsuccessful. B) When started, Linux Mint VM syncs with the host time for a few seconds then changes.